# Get last ID after insert (always return 0)

Tags: php

I have an Sql class like this:

```
        class Sql extends PDO {
            private $connection;
            public function __construct() {
                $this->connection = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myDB", "root", "root");
            }

 (...)
```

Then I'm trying to insert a data in my db using another class "user.php". Using the "getConection" (sql class method). Like this:

```
class User {
    private $iduser;
    private $deslogin;
    private $despassword;
    private $datecad;

    (getters & setters)

public function insert() { //query & select are a SQL class method
        $sql = new Sql();
        $sql->query("INSERT INTO tb_users (deslogin, despassword) VALUES (:LOGIN, :PASS))", array(
            ':LOGIN'=>$this->getDeslogin(),
            ':PASS'=>$this->getDespassword()
        ));

            echo $sql->getConnection()->lastInsertId(); //getConnection is a Sql Class method that returns the private connection.
    }
```

Why my echo always returns 0?

Comment: is your insert query running proper?

Comment: are you using any framework?

Comment: Yes. My insert is OK. And no, i'm not using framework

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its because you need **same connection object** regarding insert query to get last inserted ID **but you are creating new connection** for getting last inserted ID. That's why you are always getting 0 as result.

See the reference :

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php#120618

**EDIT**

From your code reference its problem in your `insert` Have you mark there is one extra closing bracket

change your code to:

```
$sql->query("INSERT INTO tb_users (deslogin, despassword) VALUES (:LOGIN, :PASS)", array(
            ':LOGIN'=>$this->getDeslogin(),
            ':PASS'=>$this->getDespassword()
        )); //<------there must be only one bracket after::LOGIN, :PASS
```

Comment: Oh! There's a light! Thanks!
But how can I rescue my connection in this case? I mean.. It's a private attribute..

Comment: For this you have to show your all code regarding connection and queries

Comment: Class SQL: https://anotepad.com/notes/a6wxn8
Class USER: https://anotepad.com/notes/45cbnw

The variable names are translated.. But the code is ok.

Comment: Still returns 0 :(

Comment: The insert is working. There's a new line in database.
The last id, conversely, still returns 0.